# Trello api search query returns only 10 records?

Tags: trello

I cannot seem to get the Trello api search function to return more than 10 cards. Here is the url:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/search?query=idOrganizations:[myorg] label:green&key=[mykey]&token=[mytoken]
```

There is no limit to a normal api call, just the search. I have tried this in the Trello Sandbox, Postman, and straight URL all withe same result.

I have added the `cards_limit` parameter with no effect.

Is this a limit with the search function?

Answer (score 1):

The **Trello Search API** allows you to perform the same search that is available within Trello at the top of the window.

The reason why your search query returns only 10 records/cards is because,

**1. cards_limit (optional) - Default: 10**

**2. Valid Values: a number from 1 to 1000**

[More Details](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/#api-search-get)

Comment: Thanks Anantha - I updated the question to show how I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

I was adding the `cards_limit` parameter in the wrong place. Here is the correct placement:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/search?query=idOrganizations:[myorg] label:green&cards_limit=100&key=[mykey]&token=[mytoken]
```

Comment: Accept this answer instead of adding it to your question.